# Spring unexpected behavior in service layer

Tags: spring, exception, caching, transactional

I have a problem when calling a method to delete from the data repository.

In my service layers I have this two methods:

```
@Override
public User findById(long id) {
    List<User> users = userRepository.readUsers();
    return users.stream()
            .filter(u -> u.getId() == id)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}

@Override
@CachePut(value = "users")
@Transactional
public void deleteUserById(long id) {
    userRepository.deleteUser(id);
}
```

The problem is that when deleteUserById is called, somehow the foundById is also called and raised an exception which I am catching in an @ControllerAdvice.

Deletion is successful when I check the database but when the call is executed the response is the error in the ControllerAdvice.

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: This is the controller advice

`@ControllerAdvice
public class RestApiControllerAdvice {

    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
    public CustomErrorType handleNoSuchElementException(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        return new CustomErrorType("Resource not found");
    }
}`

Comment: ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was calling findById somewhere else after I deleted the user. Outrageous mistake! Sorry. Thank you for your time.